# Active record callbacks running before creation of associated records in create and update methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my update and create method for my game controller, I am creating some game_events. There are then after_save callbacks on my game model that should run. These callbacks generate data that I need, and are saved in their respective columns. However, the issue I'm having is that the game_events are being created it seems, after the callbacks are being called. So that my "set_events_user" callback doesn't seem to acknowledge that there are any game_events. However, if from the console I save the game a second time, the callbacks acknowledge these game_events, and the events_user data is generated fine.

Essentially the reason my controller methods for update and create look so weird is because I've tried different ways of rearrangthe order of events so that when the callbacks run, the game_events are acknowledged. I've tried extracting the bit of code where it iterates over the events_user array from the params into a seperate method, then calling save a second time in one method to get it to acknowledge the events.

```
def create
    @game = Game.create(game_params)
    authorize @game
    @game.organization_id = current_user.organization_id
    params[:events_user].each do |e|
      @game.game_events.create({
        event_type: e["event_type"],
        event_id: e["event_id"],
      })
    end
    @game.save
    render json: @game, status: :ok
  rescue StandardError => e
    render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def update
    authorize @game
    @game.game_events.destroy_all
    params[:events_user].each do |e|
      @game.game_events.create({
        event_type: e["event_type"],
        event_id: e["event_id"],
      })
    end
    @game.update(game_params)
    render json: @game, status: :ok
  rescue StandardError => e
    render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end


after_save :set_events_user


def set_events_user
        @sequence = []
        self.game_events.by_sequence.each do |e|
            @e = {}
            @e[:id] = e.id
            @e[:event_id] = e.event_id
            @e[:event_type] = e.event_type
            @e[:question_text] = e.event.question_text
            @e[:a1] = {es: e.event.a1, en: e.event.a1 }
            @e[:a2] = {es: e.event.a2, en: e.event.a2 }
            @e[:a3] = {es: e.event.a3, en: e.event.a3 }
            @e[:correct_answer] = e.event.correct_answer if e.event_type == 'Question'
            @sequence << @e
        end

        @sequence.to_json
        self.events_user = @sequence
    end
```

No error message, but I expect that the gme_events are created, the callback runs upon being saved, and the game is saved with the generated data. However, unless I save it manually from the console a second time, the first time the data is empty because it won't acknowledge game events.

Comment: indeed the `after_save` callback will be called before the game_events have been created. This is expected from the code. My suggestion is to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_events` in the `Game` model. You will need to change the naming of the fields that are submitted by the form to `game_events_attributes`. Then Rails will create the `GameEvent` associations that you are creating manually.

Comment: Hey friend - thanks, I cleaned up my controlls are bit. However, I'm still having the issue where if I call before_save, even using nested_attributes, the data generate by the callbacks still doesn't include those game_events.

Comment: Why is it expecte dthat after_save callback would be called before game_events have been created?

Comment: This controller is fundamentally broken. `.save` and `.update` don't raise errors if the record is not valid. Don't do `rescue StandardError => e` in the first place. There is no good reason why your controller should be indiscriminately rescuing pretty much anything that can happen. It will just make it hard to debug and will mask bugs and errors as validation errors. Instead use `if @game.save ... else ... end`.  Exceptions should not be used for normal application flow.

Comment: @ZacharyIrlbeck it is expected that `after_save` callback will be called before the game events are created b/c the callback is triggered by the first line of the `def create` method, but the game events are created a few lines later.

Comment: @ZacharyIrlbeck, it would be expected that `before_save` callback would not include data generated by the game_events. As an experiment to give insight, I suggest creating callbacks for all the hooks in the Game model lifecycle with log messages, and then looking at the development.log to see how the callbacks are called relative to saving the objects.

Comment: @LesNightingill - thanks for the explanation, I'll give that a try.